# Need a generic php regular expression to do preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What i tried(it's a static for cpp only)=>

```
$str1 = "&lt;pre                class=&quot;brush:cpp&quot;&gt;";

$temp =  preg_replace('/&lt;pre\s+class=&quot;brush:cpp&quot;&gt;/','<pre class="brush:cpp">',$str1);

echo $temp . "\n";
```

That outputs=>

```
<pre class="brush:cpp">
```

But the $str1 can be

```
"&lt;pre class=&quot;brush:cpp&quot;&gt;"
"&lt;pre class=&quot;brush:java&quot;&gt;"
"&lt;pre class=&quot;brush:php&quot;&gt;"
"&lt;pre class=&quot;brush:python&quot;&gt;"
```

For those the output should be=>

```
<pre class="brush:cpp">
<pre class="brush:java">
<pre class="brush:php">
<pre class="brush:python">
```

Note: I can't use html_entity_decode because the texts will contain other normal string and `&lt;br&gt;` for `<br/>`, i don't want to do html_entity_decode for all texts.

I need a generic regular expression to catch cpp/java/php/python. How can i write a generic regular expression to save that part of pattern and keep it as it is in the replace string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this will work:

```
preg_replace('/&lt;pre\s+class=&quot;brush:(cpp|java|php|python)&quot;&gt;/','<pre class="brush:$1">',$str1);
```

It uses a capturing group to capture which ending is present, and it can be one of cpp/java/php/python. The replacement is made with the backreference #1, which will place whichever ending was captured.

Here is [an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/twF5UJ).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid typing `cpp|java|php|python` explicitly? Any way to write some generic expression for these? These will be language/word with [a-z] letters.

Comment: Yes, do `([a-zA-Z]+)` instead of `(cpp|java|php|python)`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
preg_replace('/&lt;pre\s+class=&quot;brush:(.*?)&quot;&gt;/',
             '<pre class="brush:$1">',
             $str1);
```